# Can you make a 3D background in Blender but draw in character animation?

Tags: animation, shaders

I am quite new to Blender and all-things animation, but I really want to get started and I have a question.

I’m an avid fan of Japanese anime, and I’ve been a fan of Makoto Shinkai’s animation for quite a while. From what I see, I notice that he uses Blender for his background works, but a hand-drawn (2D) for his character animations. I believe he also use some Adobe AE and Premiere along side Blender. Is it done by using shaders? I’m curious whether anyone know how this is achieved as I really want to try out animation the way he does it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Look at tutorials on animating with grease pencil, might be of interest to you

Comment: Blender is Ideal for this. Start doing even a little 2D animation, and you'll see why.  In Blender, 2D drawings are now  first-class 3D  objects.